Movie about a boy with cancer that finds a magic serum that cures it
The movie starts off in a funeral. It's the young boy's neighbor who died. The boy later finds a box that contains a letter from his neighbor to him. The letter explains to the boy that his neighbor is actually much older than he looked before he died. With the letter he finds a small vial with a liquid. A liquid that is supposed to give him more time to live. He drinks it, and his cancer is cured. He also has a friend who also has cancer, but when his cancer was cured he made new friends.
The new friends don't like the kid with cancer because he is a "snitch". They later tell the boy to invite his annoying friend to play tennis, where they beat the boy up. Then at the end his friend is dying and he gives him some of the liquid, and he too is cured. 
I saw the movie on TV. I watched it in the early 2000s, the movie seemed to be of that same time. It is a real life movie, not animated. The movie originated in the Unites States. It is in English. 
